# Study convergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Study convergent sequence of real numbers given by

$x_{n+1} = ax_{n} + \frac{b}{x_{n}}, (\forall) n\in N$, where $a, b, x_{0}\in ( 0, \infty)$.

What happens if $a, x_{0}\in (0, \infty)$ but $b<0$?

Comment: When $b>0$ all the $x_n$ are positive, which makes the sequence a bit easier to study; for example, if $a>0$ then the sequence is also increasing.  If $b<0$ then more complicated things can happen.

Comment: Note that this is not well defined. If $a = x_0 = 1$ and $b= -1$ then what is $x_2$?

Comment: You might want to start adding your thoughts to your questions and the steps you tried to solve them.

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure about my proof, so please pay attention to the details and tell me if something is wrong. What I will try to prove is that the succession defined by $$x_{n+1}=x_{n}+ \frac{1}{x_{n}}$$ diverges for $x_{0}\leq 1$. In fact we can use induction on n to prove that $$x_{n}>\sum_{1}^n \frac{1}{k},\forall n\geq 1.$$ It is true that $x_{1}=x_{0}+ \frac{1}{x_{0}}>1, (\frac{1}{x_{0}}\geq 1)$. Let us suppose that  $x_{n}>\sum_{1}^n \frac{1}{k},$, then: $$x_{n+1}=x_{n}+ \frac{1}{x_{n}}>\sum_{1}^n \frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{x_{n}}.$$By induction we now prove that $\frac{1}{x_{n}}\geq \frac{1}{n+1}:$ we know that $x_{0}\leq1$, and suppose $x_{n}\leq n+1$. Now we know that $x_{1} \geq 1$, which implies (the succession is monotonically increasing) $x_{n} \geq 1 \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{x_{n}} \leq 1$ then: $$x_{n+1}=x_{n}+ \frac{1}{x_{n}} \leq n+2.$$ This proves the assert. Now let's complete the proof for every $a, b, x_{0} >0$. This should not be difficult: first of all let us consider the same succession as before with $x_{0}>1$, can you see that it is the same as choosing it's inverse (say $x'_0=\frac{1}{x_0}$), for which we know the succession diverges? Now let us consider that: $$y_{n+1}=ay_n + \frac{b}{y_n} \geq cx_{n+1}, c=\min \lbrace a, b\rbrace.$$This should prove that your succession diverges.